# Why X = np.array() is returning an array of size (N, 1) and (N,) at different occasions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spyder

Actually, I have several questions.
I am working on a simple machine learning project using stock market data on Anaconda Spyder IDE. I am creating a numpy array from an specific column of a dataframe by this code:

```
Y = np.array (dataframe ['column name'])
```

The problem is, for one dataset, Y has a size of (N,), and for another dataset, size of Y is (N, 1). The dataset contains stock market price of some stocks. Specifically, when I am loading the dataset from downloaded csv files (Having about 250 data rows and 6 columns) size of Y is **(N,)**. But when I use *pandas_datareader* to import data from yahoo, size of Y is **(N, 1)**. I was importing stock data for 500 days for 6 stocks. (N, 1) size is causing problems for some of my calculations I have done next.

So, my question is, why above portion of code is returning different array sizes for Y? And can I predetermine the size somehow?

Comment: Presumably you constructed the df incorrectly so that it doesn't include scalar values

Comment: When I check the dataframe, it looks alright to me. Only difference is, in case of (N,) dataset, when everything works fine, index of the dataframe are numbers. But in case of (N, 1), the index of dataframe are dates.